# Core Data migration - adding new entity and rearranging old relationships

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I am doing core data migration - manually.

I have a "Class" entity which has one-to-many relationship to "Grade" entity.

Now I want to create a new entity - say ClassTrack

- Class will have one-to-many relationship with ClassTrack = Class <--->> ClassTrack
- Move the Grades relationship to ClassTrack so = ClassTrack <--->> Grades

With this I want to create a new ClassTrack object for **each day a grade was recorded** and then add the grades belonging to that date to the ClassTrack/Grades relationship.

**So how do I**

- create the new ClassTrack object - Custom migration policy
- create the relationship with the pertaining Grades for a date.

So for example:
Grades have been created on 
- 1/12/2012 @9:00 am
- 1/12/2012 @10:00 am
- 1/15/2012 @8:45 am

I want to create a new ClassTrack entity for 1/12/2012 and 1/15/2012. 
Add the two 1/12/2012 grades to the first ClassTrack's relationship and the 1/15/2012 to second ClassTrack's relationship.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.